# Compare first row from 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 Tables F1, F2 and F3.
The three have the same columns (C1 to C5)

Is it possible to compare the three first rows of each table? Then the three second rows ... Until the three last rows? Thank you

I have used an order by clause and the comparaison is done after each update of the table so I just need to know how to say that the current first row is exactly the same as the second one AND the third one.

Comment: There is no such thing as the "first row" in a table of a relational database. Rows in a table are not sorted. You can only talk about "first" or "last" or "second" if you supply an `order by` that sorts the _result_.

Comment: You should join your tables on ROWNUM, but take into account the above comment. Then, define "Compare" : Do you want to list only differences? Do you want to list everything side-by-side, etc...

Comment: Sample data expected results.  ***Sure this is possible*** but what is it that you expect in the results?  I'm not sure what you mean by "COMPARE"  are we looking for "MINUS" and only show rows that differ? thus sample data expected results clarify your question.  I'd probably use `Floor(RowNumber()/3)` to get each grouping of 3... and use analytic row_number() to get rows in right order.

Comment: Thank you for yor answers.
@ThomasG 

I would like to see if column C1 is the same for at least two 'first rows' of my 3 tables, then I suppose that the whole row is the same. ( for each row if F1.C1 = F2.C1 OR F1.C1 = F3.C1 OR F2.C1 = F3.C1 then F1 = F2 = F3 or something like this)

Comment: There is a fundamental flaw in your question. Suppose the three tables were the same, and then someone deleted the fifth row (however "fifth" is defined) only from the third table. So now the comparison will say the ninth row in the last table is different from the first two tables (it is, indeed, the same as the TENTH row in the first two tables). I see no possible use for the comparison the way you are requesting it. What does make sense is to have a common primary key to all three tables, and compare by primary key, not by "order".

Comment: Add sample data and expected output also what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have used an order by clause and the comparaison is done after each update of the table so I just need to know how to say that the current first row is exactly the same as the second one AND the third one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the comparison is done directly after an update so I have assumed that you know the values of the last updated row and with "current first row" you mean the last updated row then you can simply do

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM F1 
WHERE C1 = $value1
  AND C2 = $value2
  AND C3 = $value3
  AND C4 = $value4
  AND C5 = $value5
```

and see if COUNT is >= 3 or not.